# Any hand drill device that can accept any kind screw drivers tools

Tags: screwdriver

From my knowledge, a hand drill looks something like the following:

[image]

Usually, this kind of hand drill allows one to change drill bit.

However, I would like to know if there is some tool that look like a hand drill but allow one to attach any kind of screw driver tools to it.
(It can be hand drill with special chuck that can hold on the handle of any screw drivers)

[image]

Comment: Having tried this there are very limited situations when it would be useful. The gearing gives you speed at the expense of torque, and the drill isn't designed to be held into the screw head very firmly. So for typical Philips or similar wood screws it would be more trouble than it's worth. For long machine screws where you don't need much torque until the last moment it could be good. A spiral ratchet screwdriver would be better even then.

Comment: Right idea, but you need a different tool.  See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You realize that they make screwdriver bits to go into drills that will also go into the chuck of your hand drill. You can get longer bits that will fit easily into the chuck, for example:
[image]

You can also get magnetic extenders that will fit into the chuck and then hold a standard bit:

[image]

Note: photos are only examples and are not an endorsement of Sony product.

Comment: It is possible that the jaws of the chuck don't quite open wide enough for a 1/4" hex bit as the chuck may be only 6mm. If so a bit holder can be filled down (cheaper ones are easier to file).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use.  My throughput is as good as a power drill, but with very precise control.

A speedwrench with a square head intended for sockets.  You grab the handle at one end, and crank the tool with the other hand.  It's faster than you think.

[image] [image source](http://www.steritool.com)

A magnetic [bit holder](http://amzn.to/2gAPXxT) aka bit adapter

[image: enter link description here]

Common (at least in the USA) [bits](http://www.brownells.com/items/torx-set.aspx) for the screw I'm driving. These bits are intended for power drill/drivers used in drywall and decking.

[image]  [image]

Comment: A bit-brace also works (and has somewhat better handles for the job) though you'll find very few of those new - but many, many used ones. What's particularly handy is to have several with different "swing" (the offset of the handle) which offer you different "gearing" - the standard is 10" swing which is 5" offset - it's particularly amusing if you wait until everybody's battery is dead, and pull it out and keep screwing... An "eggbeater" drill as shown in the question would be difficult to use on any but the smallest screws.